# Add classes with Javascript rollover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to add a group of classes ontop of an image that only appear when the user rolls over.

**Please see this as a working example:**

http://www.warface.co.uk/clients/warface.co.uk/
(**CLICK the red arrow at the top**)

You will notice a horizontal list of images and text, desired effect will list all images and the yellow block with text will be the rollover effect.

**CSS**

```
<li><a class="project-thumb"><img src="images/_scroll1s.jpg" alt="">
    The London Police</a></li>
    <li><div class="project-thumb">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>The London Police</h2></a>
            <a class="view-project">View Project</a>
                </div><!--content END -->   
                    </div><!--project-thumb END --> 
                    </li></ul>
```

Could you please advise on the correct markup for the javascript replacement effect.

Many thanks

Comment: You should use .stop() when the user hovers over an image, so that actions will not be queued

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you use a javascript library like jQuery. jQuery makes it insanely easy to do a class change on a hover event.

1. Add jquery in your `<head>` tag. Use the one from googles CDN:

   ```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Add something like this:

   ```
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     // find the image inside the link with the class project-thumb and add a hover event
     $("a.project-thumb img").hover(
       function () {
         // add a class to the closest li. $(this) is the image
         $(this).closest('li').addClass('theClassYouWantToAdd');
       }, 
       function () {
         $(this).closest('li').removeClass('theClassYouWantToRemove');
       }
     );
   });
   </script>
   ```

Documentation for the hover event: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

That should work :)

Comment: Thanks very much for this Adam, very clear and concise just what I was looking for :)